QRhi uniform buffer re-usage
Is it correct that dynamic uniform buffers can only be used once per frame with the QRhi rendering layer (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qrhiresourceupdatebatch.html#updateDynamicBuffer)?
For instance, this will not work because the last assigned value to mvp will be visible to all draw() calls:
QRhiCommandBuffer *cb = swapChain->currentFrameCommandBuffer();
QRhiResourceUpdateBatch *resUpdates = rhi->nextResourceUpdateBatch();
QRhiBuffer* ubuf = ...;

cb->beginPass(...);
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
  mvp = ...;
  resUpdates->updateDynamicBuffer(ubuf, 0, 64, mvp.constData());
  cb->draw(...);
}
cb->endPass();

Do I have to create an uniform buffer for each possible mvp value (which can result in a lot of buffers)? Or is there a better way?
Regards,

Create multiple uniform buffers or use a larger buffer and update it in chunks
